# 50v capacitor in a 40v circuit

Tags: capacitor

I am Making a Power Supply, There is a 40v rail that needs a 10000uf cap, I was wondering if it is safe to use a 50v rated cap, Should i be worried that it is close to the Limit? The Brand of the capacitor is Elna.

Comment: That is an extremely large cap. Does your supply have inrush/current limiting?

Comment: What is feeding the capacitor?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The suppy is current limited, but this is before any of the circuity

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The cap is before any of the circuity so There is only 120v to 28v Transformer and a Bridge Rectifier. The power supply will be rated for 0-30v 0-10A

Answer (score 1):

Under full load you're close to 40V peak- you need to allow for high mains voltage and transformer regulation (voltage will rise under light load).

50V should just be okay if transformer regulation is good (usually is for larger transformers). Elna is a good brand.

Comment: Hmmm If i plan on using a rewound MOT should i be worried?

Comment: Personally I would go 63V and have plenty of margin.

Comment: You're probably right I just found a good deal 2 for 5 dollars  thought it was worth a try vs one for 6.